# Three model and a many-to-many relation: Is it possible with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem when doing something as simple as `teacher.provider`. It returns `nil` (Just in case, I know I can do teacher.course.provider, but that's not the point of the question).

Let me explain it further:

Among others, I have three classes: `Provider`, `Course` and `Teacher` and one that glues together Course and Teachers establishing a many-to-many relation, `StaffProfile`.

#### Associations

**Provider**

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :teachers, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :calls, through: :courses

end
```

**Course**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :staff_profiles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :teachers, through: :staff_profiles

    belongs_to :provider

end
```

**Teacher**

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :staff_profiles, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :courses, through: :staff_profiles

    belongs_to :provider

end
```

**StaffProfile**

```
class StaffProfile < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :course
    belongs_to :teacher

end
```

#### Where the problem happens

I detected it on teachers controller in the action create:

```
def create
    course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    teacher = course.teachers.create(teacher_params)

    # Here is where I have the problem. teacher.provider gives nil instead of returning the associated course provider.
    redirect_to teachers_path(provider_id: teacher.provider.id)
end
```

Given the relations I defined, shouldn't Rails autofill the provider_id field in the teacher created through the course? Just in case, this is what the teacher looks like once created (note the lack of provider_id):

```
#<Teacher:0x007fc0746f7110
 id: 76,
 provider_id: nil,
 first_name: "mermelada",
 last_name: "",
 cv: "",
 linkedin_id: "",
 twitter_id: "",
 created_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 15:21:55 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 15:21:55 UTC +00:00,
 photo_file_name: nil,
 photo_content_type: nil,
 photo_file_size: nil,
 photo_updated_at: nil,
 role: "">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `params[:course_id]` exists then rails won't set the provider id as you're doing `course.teachers.create(teacher_params)`, instead it will create the staff profile automatically.

Comment: What is the value of `params` when you have the issue?  Maybe it's doing the `course.teachers.create...` part rather than the `provider.teachers.create...` part.

Comment: You're going to get some confusion because of the "circle" in your schema.  A teacher is associated with a single provider but they can also be associated with multiple providers via courses.  Can you rework your schema to avoid any circular relationships like this?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, please see the edit.

Comment: @japed please see the edit.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, good point. How would you change the schema in order to specify that a teacher belongs ONLY to one provider but still, maintaining the many-to-many relation between course and teacher?

Comment: Can you not create both courses and teachers through the provider?  Then on courses have checkboxes to set which teachers are on that course and on teachers have checkboxes to set which courses they teach? With the checkboxes you can populate them with courses/teachers through the provider respectively.  It would still be circular though and Max is right, the best way would be to avoid a circular argument.

Comment: I don't think that's logically possible, but i don't understand the real-life situation you are trying to model.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, a Provider can have Teachers that are not associated to any Courses. A Teacher can teach in zero or more Courses and a Course can have zero or many Teachers (zero if it's online for example).

Comment: So do you need a link between providers and courses?  Or can you just get a providers' courses via its teachers?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, there can be courses without teachers, so I need a link between Providers and Courses.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is because `course.teachers.create` is using the `StaffProfile` relationship, and not the `Provider` one.

You should manually assign the provider:

```
    course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    teacher = course.teachers.new(teacher_params)
    teacher.provider = ...
    teacher.save!
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there is a way of forcing Rails to look up one reference and not the other.